# How to set default option d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a drop down list in my plot to select the point user wants to display. A is green. B is yellow and it is my default option. When the plot is first loaded, I want only yellow points showed in the plot. But here it shows all the points in the data. Can anyone tell me how do I fix it?

```
var defaultOption = ["B"];
var dropDown = d3.select("#filter").append("select")
                .attr("type", "AB")
                .attr("class","list");

var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
       .data(d3.map(data, function(d){return d.type;}).keys())
       .enter()
       .append("option") 
      .property("selected", function(d){
    return d == defaultOption;})  
     .text(function (d) { return d; })
      .attr("value", function (d) { return d; });

    dropDown.on("change", function() {
  var selected = this.value;
  displayOthers = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
  display = this.checked ? "none" : "inline";

  svg.selectAll(".circles")
      .filter(function(d) {return selected != d.type;})
      .attr("display", displayOthers);

  svg.selectAll(".circles")
      .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.type;})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Move the part which filters circle in a function like below `showCircles`

```
showCircles(dropDown.node());//this will filter initially
dropDown.on("change", function() {
  showCircles(this);//this will filter the circles on change of select
});
//function to show circles as per the select box
function showCircles(me){
  console.log(me);
  var selected = me.value;
  displayOthers = me.checked ? "inline" : "none";
  display = me.checked ? "none" : "inline";

  svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .filter(function(d) {
      return selected != d.type;
    })
    .attr("display", displayOthers);

  svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .filter(function(d) {
      return selected == d.type;
    })
    .attr("display", display);
}
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bo8yzSScXPYBfojuqBnH?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: for the `dropDown.node()` what does it return? For `selection.node()` it states that it will return 1st non-null element in current selection. From console log it shows _<select name="dept-list" class="filter">_